# Azure Data Factory - How to force data truncation instead of erroring out or disabling errors?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have an excel sheet that I feed into an azure data factory pipeline. One column I have is a 'state' field, that is limited to 2 nvarchar characters for a normal state abbreviation. However, sometimes we receive bad data for this column, such as extra white space or a full state name.

Rather than put sanitation logic into my data flow, I want my data to just be automatically truncated. For example, if the value was 'Texas', it would insert 'Te' into the column. The validity of this column isn't super important, and we will manually find errors like this and update as needed.

I don't want to turn off all error checking, just this specific truncation error. And I would like it to go ahead and insert the characters it can insert, rather than skipping the row.

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> To force data truncation instead of erroring out or disabling errors?

To achieve you need to use dataflow activity with derived column and then set their substring for given column.

---

- Create data flow and add Excel file as a source and the take a derived column and for the `state` column set the `substring(STATE,0,2)`
  [image]

**Data preview for Derived column:**

[image]